# Manage ManyToMany relationship in Websauna Admin Panel

Tags: sqlalchemy, colander, deform, colanderalchemy, websauna

I have a model where a lot of ManyToMany connections. I need a smart way to manage from Admin Panel. When creating a campaign model I need to connect to other models. Does Websauna have something like Django Inline foms?

```
class Campaign(Base, BaseMixin):
    name = Column(String())
    created_at = Column(UTCDateTime, default=now, nullable=False)
    updated_at = sa.Column(UTCDateTime, onupdate=now)
    owner_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'))

    workers = relationship('Worker',
                           secondary=CampaignWorker.__table__,
                           back_populates='campaign')
    recipients = relationship('Recipient',
                              secondary=CampaignRecipient.__table__,
                              back_populates='campaign')
    accounts = relationship('Account',
                            secondary=CampaignAccount.__table__,
                            back_populates='campaign')
    messages = relationship('Message',
                            back_populates='campaign')

    message_deliveries = relationship('MessageDelivery',
                                      secondary=CampaignMessageDelivery.__table__,
                                      back_populates='campaign')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deform can do [inline forms as sequences](http://deformdemo.repoze.org/sequence_orderable/).

However, as automatically generating forms from ManyToMany relationships is complex, you need to manually construct the Deform schema.

You can do this by overriding [FormView.create_form()](https://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.crud.views.html#websauna.system.crud.views.FormView.create_form) that returns a `deform.Form` object with your custom schema with sequences.

Then, you need to also override [Edit.save_changes()](https://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.crud.views.html#websauna.system.crud.views.Edit.save_changes) and/or [Add.build_object()](https://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.crud.views.html#websauna.system.crud.views.Add.build_object) that would read incoming appstruct (dict) and create or update objects in ManyToMany relationships.